# Using PHP to get the value of input type range onchange

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get the value of a range slider after it moves and then update my page. I have approached this by using "onchange" and calling some javascript to set a value to a text box and using php to get that value. The php does not even grab the value from the text area on load and I am not sure why. It says the id of the input text box is an "unidentified index." There might be a simple thing wrong or I may be approaching it completely wrong. I am new to this...

Here is the code for the slider.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>

        function printValue(sliderID, textbox) {
            var x = document.getElementById(textbox);
            var y = document.getElementById(sliderID);
            x.value = y.value;
        }

        window.onload = function() { printValue('slider1', 'rangeValue1')};
</script>
          </head>
  <body>

<form action='slider.php' method='get'>
<input id="slider1"  type="range" min="100" max="500" step="10" onchange="printValue('slider1','rangeValue1')">
<input id="rangeValue1" type="text" size="2">
</form>

<?php
echo $_GET['#rangeValue1'];
?>


  </body>
</html>
```

The js function does set input text box, but the php script doesn't happen. I need to get the value in PHP because the page I'm including it in is written in PHP. I don't know if, or how, the page has to be reloaded. I tried using location.reload() in the onchange function and it just continuously loaded the page.. Please help! Any input will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to send the value in the slider to a PHP page? If so you probably want to use a form

Comment: well the slider will be part of the PHP page. And the PHP page will update when a user users the slider

Comment: I don't quite get it. Are you sending rangeValue1 as a URL parameter? That's the only way to access it through `$_GET`.

Comment: Would $_POST work in this situation? I have never used it before and I am not quite sure the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be getting Javascript and PHP mixed up.

PHP is run solely on your server when a browser accesses a php file. The output of the php file (like when you use `echo`) is sent as a webpage. However, Javascript is run solely in the browser. To make them communicate, you will need to load another webpage (or reload the current webpage). You can either use a form or directly craft the URL (probably easier in this case).

So you could do something like this inside `printValue()`:

```
location.querystring="?value=" + x.value;
```

This will create a GET argument, which you can access with `$_GET['value']`, and reload the page.

**EDIT:** Performance Warning!

Every time the slider is moved, your server will end up resending the webpage, which could slow down the server. You might want to only send the new value after the user has clicked a button or something, in which case it would be easier to use a form.

Comment: okay that makes sense. What's the proper to reload the page. I called location.reload() in the printValue() function but the page is just continuously reloading..

Comment: @kirie That's because it is running `printValue()` every time the page loads. Did you mean `document.getElementById('slider1').onchange` instead of `window.onload`?